# Explicitly linking a local shared object library

Tags: python, c, gcc, makefile, centos6

I'm working on setting up a `Makefile` for compiling Python wrappers for a C library. The contents of the file are below (with library names altered for infosec reasons). The line numbers are for reference and are not included in the file data itself.

```
  1 CC = gcc                    
  2 CFLAGS = -Wall -fPIC -shared
  3 EXAMPLE_LIB = example
  4 PYTHON = /usr/include/python2.6
  5 LIBS = -L./$(EXAMPLE_LIB) -lexample
  6 INCLUDE = -I./$(EXAMPLE_LIB)/include -I$(PYTHON)
  7 DEPS = test.h
  8 OBJ = test.o
  9 SHARED = test.so
 10 
 11 .PHONY : build
 12 
 13 all: build $(SHARED)
 14 
 15 build:
 16    ./$(EXAMPLE_LIB)/config shared
 17    $(MAKE) -C $(EXAMPLE_LIB)
 18 
 19 %.o: %.c $(DEPS)
 20    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c -o $@ $<
 21 
 22 $(SHARED): $(OBJ)
 23    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@ $+
 24 
 25 clean:
 26    $(MAKE) clean -C $(EXAMPLE_LIB)
 27    rm $(OBJ)
 28    rm $(SHARED)
```

The `EXAMPLE_LIB` shared object file `example.so` is compiling properly and exists at `<project-directory>/example/example.so` and the proper header files for the 3rd party library exist at `<project-directory>/example/include`.

The problem I'm having is that a different version (with less features) of the `example.so` shared object library is installed on the global system and is being linked in my library (`test.so`) instead of the local (self-compiled) copy. This causes an `undefined symbol` error when attempting to import the library in Python.

When I check the `test.so` shared object library using `ldd` I see that `/usr/lib64/example.so.1` is being loaded instead of `<project-directory>/example/example.so`. Or to demonstrate:

```
[mike@tester myproject]$ ldd test.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff803ff000)
    example.so.1 => /usr/lib64/example.so.1 (0x00007f98700e8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f986fd55000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f986fb50000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f986f93a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003afda00000)
```

**Is there an option I can pass to GCC to tell it to explicitly link the local version of the shared object library?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `-L` just adds a directory to the search path, and `-l` just finds the library anywhere on the search path. So:

```
LIBS = -L./$(EXAMPLE_LIB) -lexample
```

… might look for `libexample.so` (or `libexample.a`!) in `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/lib64`, etc., before looking in `./example`.

See [Link Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) and [Options for Directory Search](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) in the GCC docs for details.

If you want to specify a library explicitly, just pass its path to the linker:

```
LIBS = ./$(EXAMPLE_LIB)/libexample.so
```

As the docs explicitly say:

> The only difference between using an -l option and specifying a file name is that -l surrounds library with ‘lib’ and ‘.a’ and searches several directories.

So, if you don't want it to search several directories, don't use `-l`.

Comment: My understanding of GCC is not particularly strong. In the example above should it work to change `LIBS = -L./$(EXAMPLE_LIB) -lexample` to `LIBS = ./$(EXAMPLE_LIB)/libexample.so` or is there an option I need to use?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Sorry for not being clearer. Hopefully the edited answer is more better?

Comment: I'm still having linking issues in my particular case but this answer seems to explain the crux of my problem.